# Getting less number of elements while printing set

Tags: set, sliding-window

In maximum length Subs-string question, I am getting correct output length but while printing set it gives less elements.  any help ?

Comment: Can you add more details (langage, what you tried, etc.)

Comment: class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        
        int n=s.length();
        Set<Character> set=new HashSet<>();
        int result=0;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        
        while(j<n){
            if(!set.contains(s.charAt(j))){
                set.add(s.charAt(j));
                j++;
                result=Math.max(set.size(),result);
        }else{
            set.remove(s.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        }
        System.out.println(set);
        return result;
        
    }
}